# Images in custom class not populating imagelist

Tags: c#, image, class, imagelist

I'm trying to populate a listview through an imagelist using a class that contains a list of another class which holds an image.

Album Class:

```
public class Camera
{
    List<Photo> _photos = new List<Photo>();
    string _title = string.Empty;

    public List<Photo> Photos
    {
        get
        {
            return this._photos;
        }
        set
        {
            this._photos = value;
        }
    }
```

Photo Class

```
public class Photo
{

    Image _photo = null;
    String _description = string.Empty;


    public Image PhotoImage
    {
        get
        {
            return this._photo;
        }
        set
        {
            this._photo = value;
        }
    }
```

Relevant Code

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        btnCapture.Enabled = false;

        this.listAlbum.View = View.LargeIcon;
        this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(64, 48);
        this.listAlbum.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;

        foreach (EncoderDevice edv in EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video))
        {
            comboCameraSelect.Items.Add(edv.Name);
        }            
    }
private Image GetScreenShot()
    {
        Image temp = null;

        using (Image screenImage = new Bitmap(panelPreview.Width, panelPreview.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screenImage))
            {                    
                Rectangle rectanglePanelVideoPreview = panelPreview.Bounds;
                Point sourcePoints = panelPreview.PointToScreen(new Point(panelPreview.ClientRectangle.X, panelPreview.ClientRectangle.Y));
                g.CopyFromScreen(sourcePoints, Point.Empty, rectanglePanelVideoPreview.Size);
            }

            temp = screenImage;
        }

        return temp;

    }

public void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Photo p = new Photo();
        p.PhotoImage = GetScreenShot();            

        album.Photos.Add(p);

        this.imageList1.Images.Add(p.PhotoImage);

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.ImageIndex = j;
        item.ImageKey = j.ToString();
        this.listAlbum.Items.Add(item);

        j = (j + 1);
    }
```

When the program gets to-

```
this.imageList1.Images.Add(p.PhotoImage);
```

it throws an exception saying the parameter is invalid, though it is an image.

The listview appears to gain indexes as a scrollbar appears after a number of cycles, but no thumbs are showing, nor is anything selectable.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: is your `PhotoImage` is type of `System.Drawing.Image`?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Yes, it is.